# Apple ecosystem - password management is inconsistent

Tags: macos, ios, password, keychain

I have an iPhone 11 and a 2020 MBP running Catalina and the password management between the devices is inconsistent.  For example: yesterday I updated a password through Safari (MBP) on website X.  When I return to that website on my MBP, autofill works.  So far, so good.

But there is a problem I have with the performance of the KeyChain: the password was not updated on my iPhone.

I'd like to know if there is any way I can force a push/pull to the keychain cloud to keep my passwords up to date.

Comment: This site works better with one question per post. You can also ask separate questions in separate posts if necessary.

Comment: Do you have iCloud keychain enabled on both devices?